# Left-handed fermion oscillating into right-handed fermion

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, fermions, dirac-equation, chirality

Given a Dirac fermion $\psi$
$$\mathcal{L} = \bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi - m \bar{\psi}\psi \ ,$$
which can be written in terms of chiral left and right handed fields as
$$\mathcal{L} = \bar{\psi}_L \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi_L + \bar{\psi}_R \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi_R - m \left(\bar{\psi}_L\psi_R + \bar{\psi}_R\psi_L\right) \ , $$
If I start with a purely left-handed particle with energy $\omega$ travelling in some direction, what is the probability to find a right handed particle after time $t$?

I expect the answer to be that in the non-relativistic case one should turn into the other on time-scales $\sim m^{-1}$, while in the relativistic regime this should be multiplied by some power of $m/\omega$...

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zitterbewegung).